# Unable to decode in Android after encoding in PHP

Tags: php, android

```
byte[] data  = Base64.decode(jsonChildNode.optString("profilePicture"),Base64.DEFAULT);
 String profilePicture =  new String(data,"UTF-8");
```

My php encode:

```
$row1['profilePicture'] = base64_encode($row1['profilePicture']);
```

The output from Android is: ???JFIF????...
It's not displaying the picture.

Comment: if you see JFIF - picture is probably decoded. Try not to convert it to string, use byte array directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are loading the image as string and not processing it back to binary.

```
ImageView imgViewer = (ImageView) findViewById(id.of.your.img_viewer);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

imgViewer.setMinimumHeight(dm.heightPixels);
imgViewer.setMinimumWidth(dm.widthPixels);
imgViewer.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

As you can see, in this example the data in byte array is loaded to a Bitmap object so that you can get the image representation.